# How would I rotate certain things or counteract rotation in js?

Tags: javascript, android

I am working on a clock script in JS and I encountered a problem when I was animating handle as a test because I was using setInterval to animate and everytime I rotated, it rotated not just the handle, it rotated EVERYTHING since setInterval repeats the same code over and over again, please help!
here is my code:

```
function clockEffect(){
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();
var l =  0;
var lt =  -100;
setInterval(function(){
ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
ctx.fillStyle="black";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,400,400);
ctx.strokeStyle="white";
ctx.fillStyle="white";
ctx.lineWidth="10";
ctx.strokeWidth
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(200,200,200,200,0,360);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.lineWidth="1";
ctx.font="60px Arial";
ctx.strokeText("12",168,60);
ctx.strokeText("3",340,210);
ctx.strokeText("9",30,210);
ctx.strokeText("6",184,360);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.translate(200,200);
ctx.rotate(20*Math.PI/180);
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(l,lt);
ctx.translate(-200,-200);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
},40);
}
var called = clockEffect();
```

Comment: wouldn't hurt to post your code

Comment: you need to put the code in your question. You are describing an issue you have, which requires the code too, to have a look and figure out the issue

Comment: Okay guys, I added my code :)! Still haven't figured it out though